# How to improve watering crops in Stardew valley on beach farm?

Tags: stardew-valley

I have lots of crops on my farm in Stardew Valley and watering has become a huge problem, I can't get sprinklers either because I am on a beach farm. Does anyone know how I can automate watering without sprinklers or at least make it quicker? Also I am on Nintendo Switch if you need to know.

Answer (score 7):

There is sadly no way to automate the watering when playing on the Switch. You can make it quicker by upgrading your watering can at the blacksmith's, to increase the area you can water in one go (hold down Y). Other than that, there is only one way to make it less of a chore, and that is to use retaining soil.

Retaining soil comes in three variants: Basic, Quality, and Deluxe. [Basic Retaining Soil](https://stardewvalleywiki.com/Basic_Retaining_Soil) gives a chance of about 33% that a crop tile remains watered overnight, [Quality Retaining Soil](https://stardewvalleywiki.com/Quality_Retaining_Soil) gives a 66% chance, and [Deluxe Retaining Soil](https://stardewvalleywiki.com/Deluxe_Retaining_Soil) a 100% chance.

All three can be added before planting or during any stage of crop growth, and using the deluxe version when planting means you will only have to water a crop once.